# Is there a way of joining 2 tables and verify the data they have

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 complex tables one is a main table and the other one is derived from main table. I want to join the derived table to main and validate the main table entries where by they must not be null.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3EuO.png]

Comment: OK. What is stopping you? No idea what you are trying to do here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You went through all the trouble of posting a question and then vanished. Why bother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to revisit your table design for sure.

I am not very clear what you are looking for, but i feel that you are looking for entires in the derived table for which one or more values are null. For this scenario you can write query like following.

```
   select distinct mt.mainid from maintable mt
    inner join derivedtable m on mt.mainid=m.id and m.name='MainId'
    inner join derivedtable u on mt.mainid=u.id and u.name='UserId'
    inner join derivedtable r on mt.mainid=r.id and r.name='RoleId'
    where (m.value is null or u.value is null or r.value is null)
```